# Completion of ring as direct limit

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

If $X$ is a variety and $x \in X$, there are several ways to look locally around the point $x$:

1. **Localisation**: taking the direct limit over open immersions around $x$.
2. **Henselisation**: taking the direct limit over étale maps around $x$.
3. **Completion**: taking an inverse limit.

I would like to know if completing can be seen as taking a direct limit over a certain class of maps. Let me state the problem more formally.

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\frak{m}$ and let $\hat{A}$ be its completion with respect to $\mathfrak{m}$.

Suppose that the map $A \rightarrow \hat{A}$ is regular (apparently this is the case if $A$ is an excellent local ring). By Popescu's theorem $\hat{A}$ is a direct limit of smooth (finitely presented) $A$-algebras.

I would like to know if $\hat{A}$ is actually a direct limit of étale $A$-algebras or if there is another characterisation of such maps.

To put the result into context, the henselisation $A^h$ of $A$ is obtained as a direct limit of étale $A$-algebras with a distinguished point and prescribed residue field.

Comment: I don't know what happens in char p, but in char 0, this does not seem to ind-étale: $\Omega_{\mathbb Q[[T]]/\mathbb Q[T]}^1$ seems to be huge.

Comment: Let me point out another fact that the completion is subtler than localization and henselization: in order that the one computed by the usual sequential limit completion is well-behaved, i.e. the completion is complete, the ideal [should be finitely generated](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JA).

Comment: By a [theorem of Olivier](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092Z) you cannot go further than strict henselization with (weakly) etale maps. This should give a negative answer if you assume that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is separably closed. If (as for a completion) you fix the residue field this is probably also true for henselization.